# it shows output more than 4 times

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I was trying to make a program in C that basically asks the user some information about the people they live with. The code is in Spanish, but I will show you the problem.

```
    /*Miembros de la familia*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(){
    
    int personas,i,varones=0,hembras=0,opcion;
    bool mayoredad=false;
    

    printf("Indique cuantas personas viven en su casa:\n");
    scanf("%i", &personas);

    
    struct nombre{
        char primer[30];
        char segundo[30];
        char apellido[30];
    }minombre;
    
    struct fecha{
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int anio;
    }nacimiento, actual;
    
    printf("\nIngrese la fecha actual:\n");
    scanf("%i %i %i", &actual.dia, &actual.mes, &actual.anio);
    
    
    struct familia{
        struct nombre minombre;
        char cedula[10];
        struct fecha nacimiento;
        char genero;
        int edad;
    }familia[personas];
    
    
    for(i=0;i<personas;i++){
        printf("\nIndique su primer nombre, segundo nombre y apellido:\n");
        scanf("%s %s %s", &familia[i].minombre.primer, &familia[i].minombre.segundo, &familia[i].minombre.apellido);
        printf("\nPor favor escriba su numero de cedula:\n");
        scanf("%s", &familia[i].cedula);
        do{
        printf("\nIngrese la fecha de su nacimiento: (DD)(MM)(AAAA):\n");
        scanf("%i %i %i", &familia[i].nacimiento.dia, &familia[i].nacimiento.mes, &familia[i].nacimiento.anio);
        if(familia[i].nacimiento.anio>actual.anio){
            printf("Dato invalido, por favor intente nuevamente.");
        }
        }while(nacimiento.anio>actual.anio);
        familia[i].edad=actual.anio-familia[i].nacimiento.anio;
            if(familia[i].nacimiento.mes>=actual.mes && familia[i].nacimiento.dia>actual.dia){
                familia[i].edad--;
            }
            if(familia[i].edad>=18){
                mayoredad=true;
            }
        do{
            printf("Indique su genero: (f) o (m):");
            scanf(" %c", &familia[i].genero);
            if(familia[i].genero=='f'){
                hembras++;
            }else if(familia[i].genero=='m'){
                varones++;
            }
        }while(familia[i].genero!='f' && familia[i].genero!='m');       
    }
    
    do{
    printf("Registro concluido. Desea ver las estadisticas? 1(si) 2(no)");
    scanf("%i", &opcion);
    if(opcion!=1 && opcion!=2){
        printf("DATO INVALIDO, INTENTE NUEVAMENTE");
    }else if(opcion==1){
        for(i=0;i<personas;i++){
            printf("Nombre: %s %s %s\n", familia[i].minombre.primer, familia[i].minombre.segundo, familia[i].minombre.apellido);
            printf("Cedula:%s\n", familia[i].cedula);
            printf("Edad:%i\n", familia[i].edad);
            printf("Mayor de edad:\n");
            switch(mayoredad){
                case true:printf("Si");break;
                case false:printf("No");
            }
        }
        printf("Cantidad de personas en el hogar: %i\n", personas);
        printf("Varones: %i    Hembras: %i\n", varones, hembras);
    }
    }while(opcion>=2 && opcion<0);
        
    printf("Presione una tecla para salir.");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In the last do-while loop that requests the person's gender (familia[i].genero)
It is supposed to ask just once, but in the last iteration of the for loop, it displays the same question four times:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVwUs.png)
How can I fix this?

Comment: We're polite to everyone, beginner or otherwise.

Comment: Your code has several compiler warnings.  I suggest you fix those first.  In particular, you don't use  an ampersand in `scanf` with character arrays.  See https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/VerifiableVividTrapezoid

Comment: The condition `opcion>=2 && opcion<0` will never become true.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier `%i` will treat input whose suffix is `0` (and not `0x` nor `0X`) as octal number.

Therefore, `09` in your input is invalid as octal number and it will leave `9` in the stream.

This `9` is read to `familia[i].nacimiento.anio` by the next specifier.

Then, following `scanf(" %c", &familia[i].genero);` will read `2003` from the input and this will lead to the 4 extra asking.

To fix this, use `%d` specifier to read integers. `%d` spcifier will treat input as decimal number regardless of the suffix.

Comment: OMG Thank you. It also fixes a bug with the age (dead) and wether or not the person is underage.

Comment: (edad)* age in spanish

Comment: Actually I did that but now it shows that message twice exactly in the for loop's first iteration. The previous bug was always presnet in the last one